Красные артифакты в окне сцены в юнити линукс

скачал юнити создал проэкт и тут это (Linux Mint)

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.
